# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'

Tags: python, fastapi, modulenotfounderror

Here is my file structure and requirements.txt:

[image: Here is my file structure and requirements.txt]

Getting `ModuleNotFoundError`, any help will be appreciated.

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from .import models
from .database import engine
from .routers import ratings


models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()


app.include_router(ratings.router)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you were not using the right environment and python version on VSCODE.
Your environment knew your different packages, but VSCode probably did not take them into account.

The solution was, in VSCODE: `CTRL + SHIFT + P` then `Python:select interpreter` and choose the version of python linked to your environment.

You can try to change the version of python to see the consequences on your imports

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hmm..  when i started project in another direcory everything worked properly. Should i select python enterpreter everytime i open the vscode? I think that's very repetitive

Comment: No, usually it is necessary to select manually when we manipulate different environments, or when deleting an environment, creating a new git repo with a new environment via the VScode terminal, etc... 
This is not an action to be done usually, VScode takes care of it automatically, but sometimes it is necessary to do it manually.

Answer (score 10):

Try this to install all dependencies:

```
$ pip install "fastapi[all]"
```

Comment: same error. fastapi is included in env. i am buildin application with microservices i have like 5 simillar projects and only this one is throwing error, i am little bit confused

Comment: dont work to me :/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I uninstalled fastapi several times and then reinstalled it, but it didn't work.
I closed and reopened vscode several times, but it didn't work.
But when **I closed the terminal inside VScode and created a new terminal again**, the problem was solved.

Comment: Yep, same here!
Closed the current terminal and opened a new one in which the problem wasn't persisted anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
python -m pip install fastapi uvicorn[standard]
```