# FastAPI error: Cannot import name 'FastApi' from 'fastapi'

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to use FastAPI. I installed it using pip, and when I am adding (and running) it to my project like that:

```
from fastapi import FastApi
```

I am getting this error:

```
cannot import name 'FastApi' from 'fastapi' (C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\MyBank\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\__init__.py).
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113116/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-fastapi)

Comment: No, it didnt help me, I checked it, and I didnt find the problem yet.

Answer (score 15):

That should be as follows (with `API` being capitalised  at the end). Please have a look at the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/) as well.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
                        ^^^
```

Additionally, make sure **not** to name your python script file `fastapi.py`, as this would interfere with the library (when adding `from fastapi import FastAPI`), but rather use some neutral name, such as `app.py`.

Answer (score 3):

Might come from the fact that the name of your python file is actually fastapi and python is messed up by the fact that import is primarily looking at the current folder to import files then the libs.

meaning that if you have a file named : fastapi.py python will think that import fastapi means import the fastapi.py file from the current working dir and will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you walk through the [first steps](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/)

They suggest the filename `main.py`

with the following minimum working example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

After that you can run the following command:
`uvicorn main:app --reload`

If that doesn't work it would be good to share more details such as folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS Code?

Yes? Then you may want to do the following:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then search for 'Python:Select Interpreter', now you get to choose the desired environment where you have installed fastapi.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33535358)